# What are all values ISNUMERIC function finds as TRUE in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, isnumeric

Below part of my query was failing initially:

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(npx.nvcAnswer) = 1
            THEN CASE 
            WHEN ABS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer)) < 1 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer)) 
            ELSE npx.nvcAnswer 
            END
```

Below was the error we were getting:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
>       rootCause=SQLException #1: errorCode: 8114 sqlState: S0005 message: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I realized that it considers `'.'` & `'-'` as NUMERIC too.

So I added `"NOT npx.nvcAnswer in( '.' , '-')"` to it and it worked.

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(npx.nvcAnswer) = 1 AND  NOT npx.nvcAnswer in( '.' , '-')
    THEN CASE 
    WHEN ABS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer)) < 1 
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer)) 
    ELSE npx.nvcAnswer 
    END
```

After some day it started failing again with below error.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
>   rootCause=SQLException #1: errorCode: 8114 sqlState: S0005 message: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Then I changed below block and it worked: (But I failed to find what values were causing this issue)

OLD:

```
   WHEN ABS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer)) < 1 
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),npx.nvcAnswer))
```

NEW:

```
  WHEN ABS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', npx.nvcAnswer))) < 1 
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,2),PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', npx.nvcAnswer)))
```

**Ask :**

What are all values ISNUMERIC function finds as TRUE in sql server?

Comment: too long to list. I.e. some are only valid in certain combinations, such as `1d1`. You should instead, as you have done, use a whitelist of characters you do believe are valid. `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody has ever wanted to ask - "can this string of characters be converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care *which* type(s) it can be converted to)?"

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you should your Try_Cast() function instead of using complex logic to check numeric values.

ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).  Please refer below links for further detail -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql